# Stuck Ferm? Celebration Ale Clone Gravity at 1.021

Tags: fermentation, fermentation-temperature, final-gravity

Celebration Ale Clone (extract kit)
White Labs California Ale Yeast (liquid vial, no starter, I know next time I'll make a starter)
Pitched at 68 degrees and good activity 18 hours later, got up to 71 degrees for the first 4 days of fermentation, but from days 5-10 its been around 64 degrees (house got cold and didn't have a temp control system) and the last 2 days have given gravity readings of only 1.021.
I aerated by pouring back and forth between the ferm bucket and bottling bucket and shook the bucket up before pitching, which is what I usually do and seems to work well for aeration on my other batches, but I did just order an O2 aeration system for my next batch.

I also did just get a Fermwrap and Johnson Digital Temp Controller to help in temp control during the colder months.
My question is would it work to swirl the bucket a bit to resuspend some of the yeast and use the Fermwrap to get the temp back up to 70 degrees to help it get down to a FG closer to the estimated 1.012?
I don't want to create any bottle bombs with a 1.021 gravity reading.
I contacted the store (Brewer's Apprentice in Freehold, NJ) where I get my kits and they weren't to sure if that would do anything, but shouldn't it help the yeast finish up since I feel like the yeast is probably just dormant from the colder temps? White Labs suggest 68-73 degrees.
Or is there anything else I can do to help it out?

(Side Note: Read in another post that scorched wort can create unfermentable sugars resulting in a higher FG, and yes I did slightly scorch my extract cause I left the heat on for a minute when adding it, so this may be the reason)

Comment: What was the OG?

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention, 1.052

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have restarted a ferment this way, but you need to warm it up first, then resuspend the yeast.  Doing in reverse just has yeast back in a suspension of cool wort/beer and they settle back out.

That said a 1.021 extract batch, with no starter and the hopping rate of a SN Celebration Clone makes me suspect that its about as done as its going to be.  I'd warm it up and see if it gives you a couple more points.  No need to swirl really there is plenty of yeast available.

But I wouldn't set my hopes on it getting to 1.012.

It also depends on the OG as well.  You might already be at a reasonable amount of apparent attenuation.

Comment: Oh yeah forgot to mention the OG, it was 1.052. The sample I had was slightly sweet which leaves me to believe that it could drop a few more points once I heat it up. FedEx never came, so I'll have to wait until tomorrow for my Fermwrap to get it up to about 70 degrees. I'm in no rush, I plan on getting up to 70 tomorrow and let it sit for about another week, then I'll transfer to a secondary to dry hop for 2 weeks and then bottle. Thanks for the help guys!

Comment: After only 5 hours after raising the temp up to 70 with the Fermwrap there is already more airlock activity. So hopefully that means I can get it to drop that last 3 points and get it into my secondary.

Comment: The solubility of CO2 decreases with an increase in temperature.  The airlock activity you are seeing is likely just CO2 coming out as it warms up.  You might get a couple more points though I haven't had much luck.  Once the yeast is done its done regardless if there is more sugars.  If they weren't in tip top shape to start with they tend to poop out early and stay pooped.  Good luck and keep us posted.

Comment: 3 days after my last reading and the gravity has dropped to 1.018...if it stays steady its ready for my secondary

Comment: Today's reading has dropped to 1.016. I definitely believe now that the yeast just slowed down and went dormant when it got too cold and getting the temp back up to a constant 70 got them going again. Not all is lost! And it has a great hop bite, just like the real Celebration Ale.

Answer (score 0):

A good way to find out if there are any fermentable sugars left is to do a Fast Ferment test. Use a wine thief to draw some beer and put it in a jar/container/flask, do a gravity reading to confirm the 1.021 number, then pitch some yeast.

This website is really helpful with step-by-step instructions: http://braukaiser.com/wiki/index.php?title=Fast_Ferment_Test#How_to_perform_the_fast_ferment_test.3F

Hope this helps!

Comment: I have a Fast Ferment Test going right now, so we shall see how it goes.

Comment: Fast Ferm Test gave me a FG reading of 1.018, so we'll see if I can get my batch to drop that final 3 points